# proper syntax for postgres UPDATE for more than one condition?

Tags: node.js

I have the following code to use to update and existing record in a postgres database using Node.js:

```
 var mods = "UPDATE users SET login = '" + now + "' WHERE name = '" + String(req.body.usr) + "';";

 client.query(mods, function(err, result) {   
 //call `done()` to release the client back to the pool
 done(); 
  if(err){
  console.log(err);
  }
});
```

I would like to provide multiple 'WHERE' conditions instead of just one...however I am having problems with syntax.  For example I wish to do something like

```
'WHERE name = ' + String(req.body.usr) AND 'WHERE login = ' + String(req.body.password)
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am just having syntax issues with trying to provide more than one `WHERE` condition to the update query.  I thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd like you to meet a good friend of mine, his name is [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: yes I would sanitize the data before calling the UPDATE to the database...thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't write `WHERE` multiple times, just use `AND` to chain them. Or, you could google [Postgress Where](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-where/).

```js
var mods = "UPDATE users SET login = '" + now + "' WHERE name = '" + name + "' AND login ='" + login + "' AND ... ";
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, much appreciated.